# How to override line-height and height css properties that are adding from external css using inline css?

Tags: css, height, textfield

I've a text field as follows :

```
<input name="course_code" id="course_code" placeholder="Course Code" type="text">
```

The external css that applies to the above text field is as follows :

```
height: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
```

I tried to uncheck these attributes from firebug console by inspecting the textfield element and it started looking fine.

So I want to ignore these fields by using some inline css code or internal css code which could override the above two lines.

How could I do this? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `initial` and `inherit`

```
<input name="course_code" id="course_code" style="height:initial;line-height:inherit" placeholder="Course Code" type="text">
```

You could also use [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) but it will be supported only in Chrome and Firefox:

```
style="height:unset;line-height:unset"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="course_code" id="course_code" placeholder="Course Code" type="text" style="height:some      
value !important;line-height:somevalue !important">
```

!important is used to ignore all css and apply the recent one on with it passed.

Comment: It was part of the CSS1 spec and has been around forever, and was always easy enough to implement that browsers appear to have gotten it right on the first try.

At the very least (from personal experience) IE5.5+, Firefox 1+, Safari 3+, Chrome 1+.

Pretty much supported by every browser that supports CSS (which is every browser you care about). :D